# What is the name of $E_n[x]$ ?!

Tags: notation, terminology

I am writing a paper, I want to introduce the $E_n[x]$

Is it correct to write:

$E_n[x] $ represents exponential integral **of order of n**

I know $E_i[x]$ or $E_1[x]$ is called exponential integral. However, I have no Idea about the generalized version of it. Is it correct to mention **of order of n** ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think adding the terminology tag helps. I think he means a tag such as functional-analysis, or group-theory etc.

Comment: I see your point, but there is nothing to do with functional-analysis or whatever analysis. I want to know how to write a specific definition

Comment: Sorry they were just examples, I have no idea what field your question relates(which might be the problem itself haha), so whatever field you would find this you should tag (algebra, calculus, number theory, such and such)

Comment: What is this $E_n[x]$, how is it defined? Notation is rarely unique across the fields of mathematics...

Comment: @A.P. in this case, It is very well-known function; it is exponential integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research, it looks $E_n$ is called *generalised* exponential integral (for $n \neq 1$). [This paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0898122187901349) seems to suggest that *order* is indeed the correct term, although you could safely say *parameter*, too.

You should drop the second "of", though, and say something like:

> [...] where $E_n[x]$ is the (generalised) exponential integral of order $n$.

Comment: Many Thanks for the answer